# In JavaScript, can you reference a method/function name within that method/function?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, reference, webdriver-io

I am building an automation framework in JavaScript for WebdriverIO.

The "out-of-the-box" error messages aren't too helpful and I would like to add the class name and method name as part of a prefix to the error message which is thrown when the method/function fails.

I have managed to call the class name with `ClassName.name`

However, I have not found a solution to reference the method name without using some hardcoded value.

Below is a summary of the changes I would like to make.

Before:

```
setElementValue(element, value){
    try{
        this.waitForElementAndScroll(element);
        $(element).setValue(value);
    }
    catch(error){
        throw `${BasePage.name}.setElementValue: ${error.message}`;
    }
}
```

After:

```
setElementValue(element, value){
    try{
        this.waitForElementAndScroll(element);
        $(element).setValue(value);
    }
    catch(error){
        throw `${BasePage.name}.${setElementValue.name}: ${error.message}`;
    }
}
```

Where `${setElementValue.name}` is the method of referencing the name of the method/function.

Many thanks in advance!

I have tried the following with no success:

`method.name //ReferenceError: method is not defined`

`(method).name //ReferenceError: method is not defined`

`Function.name //Returns "Function"`

`Function.value //Returns "undefined"`

`constructor.name //Returns "Object"`

`setElementValue.name //ReferenceError: setElementValue is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this (very obvious) solution to work for me:

```
this.setElementValue.name
```

where the thrown error message is:

```
throw `${BasePage.name}.${this.setElementValue.name}: ${error.message}`;
```

which outputs the following error log when the method fails:

```
`BasePage.setElementValue: element ("#submit-button") still not displayed after 500ms`
```